# Bootstrap 4 specify columns in card-deck-wrapper

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="card-deck-wrapper">
   <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This code shows 4 columns in all screen sizes except xs - it change to 4 rows and one column.

**Q:** How to specify when there should be 2 rows and 2 columns? For example - when screen size is smaller than md.

@edit: It is possible to use card-columns but it does not meet all my requirements (for ex, the same height)

Comment: @LuukSkeur Not work

Comment: -1 show examples and what you have tried so far, besides that don't delete comments, other users might need this info. Also your question is not clear and not bootstrap-related since you are not using bootstrap.